# How can i disable automatic sort of DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

My Data-Tables Initialization Script is

```
$('#table').DataTable();
```

I want to disable auto sort of table column

Comment: try `"bSortable": false` , look this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/ptr63fxt/

Comment: thanks for your anwer

Comment: The correct answer is  `order: []` ...This maintain the order capabilities but does not set a default order, which is `[[0, 'asc']]` ordering the first column ascending.

Answer (score 4):

Ok,i found the solution

just add **data-order = ' '** in your table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered " id="table"  data-order=''>
```

Comment: This is actually good answer, sign your answer as a solution. Simple and effective. I have been seaching for this.
Edit: This corrupt table sorting property permanently. It is no good for stopping the initial sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Set the aaSorting option to an empty array. It will disable initial sorting,

```
"aaSorting": []
```

Example :

```
$('#you_table_id').DataTable({
    "aaSorting": []
});
```

The `aaSorting` array should contain an array for each column to be sorted initially containing the column's index and a direction string (`asc` or `desc`).

Answer (score 0):

// For updated version

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

// For older version

This is done by setting `bSortable` to false

```
$('#table').dataTable({
"bSortable": false 
});
```

*by aoColumnDefs*

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ] } );
```

*by aoColumns*

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [ 
        { "bSortable": false },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ] } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling auto-sort with custom pagination icon using Font Awesome

```
$("#table").dataTable({
    pagingType: "simple",
    ordering: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    language: {
        emptyTable: "No data available in table",
        paginate: {
            previous: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        },
        search: "",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search",
        info: "_START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_",
        infoEmpty: "",
        infoFiltered: "",
    },
    order: [] // Add this to Disable the auto-sorting
});
```